# paralell_rspec with options --exclude-pattern

Tags: ruby, rspec, parallel-testing

Trying to exclude the specs in the /home dir during the parallel run.

Tried a few things similar to the following:

`parallel_rspec myproj -n 4 -o '--exclude-pattern "myproj/spec/home/*_spec.rb"'`

`parallel_rspec ./myproj -n 4 -o '--exclude-pattern "./myproj/spec/home/*_spec.rb"'`

But it does not exclude specs in the /home dir. It runs all specs in myproj.

The following commands do exclude specs in /home dir but I need to run them in parallel:

`rspec myproj --exclude-pattern "myproj/spec/home/*_spec.rb"`

`rspec ./myproj --exclude-pattern "./myproj/spec/home/*_spec.rb"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `parallel_test` gem.

I added the following to the `.rspec_parallel` file:

```
--tag ~tagname1
--tag ~tagname2
--tag ~tagname3
```

This excluded the specs tagged with tagname1,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

I always used the `rake` task for that as [advised here](https://github.com/willbryant/parallel_rspec#usage):

```
ParallelRSpec::RakeTask.new(:prspec) do |t|
  ENV['WORKERS'] = '4'
  t.rspec_opts = '--exclude-pattern "myproj/spec/home/*_spec.rb"'
end
```

and run it as:

```
bundle exec rake prspec
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the gem `parallel_rspec` and ran `bundle install`. Then when I ran `bundle exec rake prspec`, it gave me `rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails`. Any idea why?

Comment: Unfortunately no idea, I never ran into running `parallel_rspec` outside of rails as you supposedly do.

Comment: What `rails` version are you using?

Comment: Both `3.2+`, `4.0+`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried just tried the `parallel_rspec` gem but didn't work. I think I'll go with the `parallel_tests` gem.